# my application stops when I start it

Tags: java, android, eclipse

So I just started programming in java, and tried to make a TicTicToeGame, which succeeded :) The problem is, that you can only play 1 game of TicTacToe, so I wanted to make a button to restart the game and a button to quit the game. Since I added this and try to run it on my phone it crashes when I start it up. Here is my MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.testjk;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.inputmethodservice.ExtractEditText;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener{

    private TicTacToeGame mGame;

    private Button mBoardButtons[];

    private TextView mInfoTextView;
    private TextView mHumanCount;
    private TextView mTieCount;
    private TextView mAndroidCount;

    private int mHumanCounter = 0;
    private int mTieCounter = 0;
    private int mAndroidCounter = 0;

    private boolean mHumanFirst = true;
    private boolean mGameOver = false;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mBoardButtons = new Button[mGame.getBOARD_SIZE()];
        mBoardButtons[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
        mBoardButtons[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
        mBoardButtons[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.three);
        mBoardButtons[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.four);
        mBoardButtons[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.five);
        mBoardButtons[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.six);
        mBoardButtons[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seven);
        mBoardButtons[7] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eight);
        mBoardButtons[8] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nine);

        Button mTen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ten);
        mTen.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        Button mEleven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eleven);
        mEleven.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);


        mInfoTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.information);
        mHumanCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.humancount);
        mTieCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tiesCount);
        mAndroidCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.androidCount);

        mHumanCount.setText(Integer.toString(mHumanCounter));
        mTieCount.setText(Integer.toString(mTieCounter));
        mHumanCount.setText(Integer.toString(mAndroidCounter));

        mGame = new TicTacToeGame();

        startNewGame();


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        switch (v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.ten:

            startNewGame();
            break;

        case R.id.eleven:

            MainActivity.this.finish();
            break;

        }
    }



    private void startNewGame()
    {
        mGame.clearBoard();

        for (int i = 0; i < mBoardButtons.length; i++)
        {
            mBoardButtons[i].setText("");
            mBoardButtons[i].setEnabled(true);
            mBoardButtons[i].setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickListener(i));

        }
        if (mHumanFirst)
        {
            mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.first_human);
            mHumanFirst = false;
        }
        else
        {
            mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_computer);
            int move = mGame.getComputerMove();
            setMove(mGame.ANDROID_PLAYER, move);
            mHumanFirst = true;
        }
    }

    private class ButtonClickListener implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        int location;

        public ButtonClickListener(int location)
        {
            this.location = location;
        }

        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            if (!mGameOver)
            {
                if(mBoardButtons[location].isEnabled())
                {
                    setMove(mGame.HUMAN_PLAYER, location);

                    int winner = mGame.checkForWinner();

                    if (winner == 0)
                    {
                        mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_computer);
                        int move = mGame.getComputerMove();
                        setMove(mGame.ANDROID_PLAYER, move);
                        winner = mGame.checkForWinner();

                    }
                    if (winner == 0)
                            mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_human);
                    else if (winner == 1)
                    {
                        mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_tie);
                        mTieCounter++;
                        mTieCount.setText(Integer.toString(mTieCounter));
                        mGameOver = true;
                    }       
                    else if (winner ==2)
                    {
                        mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_human_wins);
                        mHumanCounter++;
                        mHumanCount.setText(Integer.toString(mHumanCounter));
                        mGameOver = true;
                    }
                    else if (winner ==3)
                    {
                        mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_android_wins);
                        mAndroidCounter++;
                        mAndroidCount.setText(Integer.toString(mAndroidCounter));
                        mGameOver = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void setMove(char player, int location)
    {
        mGame.setMove(player,location);
        mBoardButtons[location].setEnabled(false);
        mBoardButtons[location].setText(String.valueOf(player));
        if (player == mGame.HUMAN_PLAYER)
            mBoardButtons[location].setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        else
        {
            mBoardButtons[location].setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
    }

}
```

This is my strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">testjk</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="turn_human">Jouw beurt.</string>
    <string name="first_human">Jij mag eerst beginnen.</string>
    <string name="turn_computer">computer is aan het nadenken</string>
    <string name="result_tie">Gelijkspel!</string>
    <string name="result_human_wins">net aan gewonnen!</string>
    <string name="result_android_wins">sukkel!</string>
    <string name="one">1</string>
    <string name="two">2</string>
    <string name="three">3</string>
    <string name="four">4</string>
    <string name="five">5</string>
    <string name="six">6</string>
    <string name="seven">7</string>
    <string name="eight">8</string>
    <string name="nine">9</string>
    <string name="ten">nieuw spel</string>
    <string name="eleven">stoppen</string>
    <string name="info">Info</string>
    <string name="human">JIJ:  </string>
    <string name="ties">Gelijkspel:  </string>
    <string name="android">Computer:  </string>
    <string name="contact_heading">Contact Informatie</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="contact_info">

        <b>Name:</b> Wouter\n
        <b>Achternaam</b> de Jong\n
        <b>Email</b> woutter@live.nl
        </string>
        <string name="about_heading">over </string>
        <string name="TicTacToeGame">Boter Kaas en Eieren van wouter de jong</string>


</resources>
```

This is my activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.testjk.MainActivity" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/PlayArea"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >


        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="clip_horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/one"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="@string/one"
                android:textSize="70dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/two"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="@string/two"
                android:textSize="70dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/three"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="@string/three"
                android:textSize="70dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="clip_horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/four"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="@string/four"
                android:textSize="70dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/five"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="@string/five"
                android:textSize="70dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/six"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="@string/six"
                android:textSize="70dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="clip_horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/seven"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="@string/seven"
                android:textSize="70dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/eight"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="@string/eight"
                android:textSize="70dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/nine"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="@string/nine"
                android:textSize="70dp" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/information"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|clip_horizontal|fill_horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/human"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/human" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/humancount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ties"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/ties" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tiesCount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/androidcount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/android" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/androidCount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/information"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/PlayArea"
        android:layout_below="@+id/PlayArea"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/info"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ten"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/ten" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/eleven"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:text="@string/eleven" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

TicTacToeGame.java:

```
package com.example.testjk;

import java.util.Random;

public class TicTacToeGame {

    private char mBoard[];
    private final static int BOARD_SIZE = 9;

    public static final char HUMAN_PLAYER = 'X';
    public static final char ANDROID_PLAYER = '0';
    public static final char EMPTY_SPACE = ' ';

    private Random mRand;

    public static int getBOARD_SIZE() {
        return BOARD_SIZE;
    }

    public TicTacToeGame(){
        mBoard = new char[BOARD_SIZE];

        for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE; i++)
            mBoard[i] = EMPTY_SPACE;

        mRand = new Random();
    }

    public void clearBoard()
    {
        for (int i = 0;i < BOARD_SIZE; i++)
        {
            mBoard[i] = EMPTY_SPACE;
        }
    }

    public void setMove(char player, int location)
    {
        mBoard[location] = player;
    }

    public int getComputerMove()
    {
        int move;

        for (int i = 0; i < getBOARD_SIZE(); i++)
        {
            if (mBoard[i] != HUMAN_PLAYER && mBoard[i] != ANDROID_PLAYER)
            {
                char curr = mBoard[i];
                mBoard[i] = ANDROID_PLAYER;
                if (checkForWinner() == 3)
                {
                    setMove(ANDROID_PLAYER, i);
                    return i;
                }
                else 
                    mBoard[i] = curr;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < getBOARD_SIZE(); i++)
        {
            if (mBoard[i] != HUMAN_PLAYER && mBoard[i] != ANDROID_PLAYER)
            {
                char curr = mBoard[i];
                mBoard[i] = HUMAN_PLAYER;
                if (checkForWinner() == 2)
                {
                    setMove(ANDROID_PLAYER, i);
                    return i;
                }
                else 
                    mBoard[i] = curr;
            }
        }
        do
        {
            move = mRand.nextInt(getBOARD_SIZE());
        }while (mBoard[move]==HUMAN_PLAYER || mBoard[move] == ANDROID_PLAYER);

            setMove(ANDROID_PLAYER, move);
        return move;
    }
    public int checkForWinner()
    {
        for (int i=0;i<=6;i+=3)
        {
            if (mBoard[i] == HUMAN_PLAYER && 
                mBoard[i+1] == HUMAN_PLAYER && 
                mBoard[i+2] == HUMAN_PLAYER)
                return 2;
            if (mBoard[i] == ANDROID_PLAYER && 
                mBoard[i+1] == ANDROID_PLAYER && 
                mBoard[i+2] == ANDROID_PLAYER)
                return 3;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <=2; i++)
        {
            if (mBoard[i] == HUMAN_PLAYER &&
                mBoard[i+3] == HUMAN_PLAYER &&
                mBoard[i+6] == HUMAN_PLAYER)
                return 2;
            if (mBoard[i] == ANDROID_PLAYER &&
            mBoard[i+3] == ANDROID_PLAYER &&
            mBoard[i+6] == ANDROID_PLAYER)
                return 3;

        }
        if((mBoard[0] == HUMAN_PLAYER &&
                mBoard[4] == HUMAN_PLAYER &&
                mBoard[8] == HUMAN_PLAYER)|| 
                (mBoard[2] == HUMAN_PLAYER &&
                mBoard[4] == HUMAN_PLAYER &&
                mBoard[6] == HUMAN_PLAYER))
        return 2;
    if((mBoard[0] == ANDROID_PLAYER &&
            mBoard[4] == ANDROID_PLAYER &&
            mBoard[8] == ANDROID_PLAYER)|| 
            (mBoard[2] == ANDROID_PLAYER &&
            mBoard[4] == ANDROID_PLAYER &&
            mBoard[6] == ANDROID_PLAYER))
        return 3;


    for (int i = 0; i < getBOARD_SIZE(); i++)
    {
        if (mBoard[i] != HUMAN_PLAYER && mBoard[i] != ANDROID_PLAYER)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
    }
}
```

AndroidManiFest.xml in my bin/res folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testjk"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_hoi"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

game_menu.xml in my res/menu folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >





</menu>
```

Those are all my classes I edited.
And this is the logcat I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vP6De.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package com.example.testjk;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private TicTacToeGame mGame;

    private Button mBoardButtons[];

    private TextView mInfoTextView;
    private TextView mHumanCount;
    private TextView mTieCount;
    private TextView mAndroidCount;

    private int mHumanCounter = 0;
    private int mTieCounter = 0;
    private int mAndroidCounter = 0;

    private boolean mHumanFirst = true;
    private boolean mGameOver = false;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mBoardButtons = new Button[mGame.getBOARD_SIZE()];
        mBoardButtons[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
        mBoardButtons[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
        mBoardButtons[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.three);
        mBoardButtons[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.four);
        mBoardButtons[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.five);
        mBoardButtons[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.six);
        mBoardButtons[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seven);
        mBoardButtons[7] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eight);
        mBoardButtons[8] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nine);

        Button mTen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ten);
        mTen.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        Button mEleven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eleven);
        mEleven.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);


        mInfoTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.information);
        mHumanCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.humancount);
        mTieCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tiesCount);
        mAndroidCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.androidCount);

        mHumanCount.setText(Integer.toString(mHumanCounter));
        mTieCount.setText(Integer.toString(mTieCounter));
        mHumanCount.setText(Integer.toString(mAndroidCounter));

        mGame = new TicTacToeGame();

        startNewGame();


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        switch (v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.ten:

            startNewGame();
            break;

        case R.id.eleven:

            MainActivity.this.finish();
            break;

        }
    }



    private void startNewGame()
    {
        mGame.clearBoard();

        for (int i = 0; i < mBoardButtons.length; i++)
        {
            mBoardButtons[i].setText("");
            mBoardButtons[i].setEnabled(true);
            mBoardButtons[i].setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickListener(i));

        }
        if (mHumanFirst)
        {
            mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.first_human);
            mHumanFirst = false;
        }
        else
        {
            mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_computer);
            int move = mGame.getComputerMove();
            setMove(mGame.ANDROID_PLAYER, move);
            mHumanFirst = true;
        }
    }

    private class ButtonClickListener implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        int location;

        public ButtonClickListener(int location)
        {
            this.location = location;
        }

        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            if (!mGameOver)
            {
                if(mBoardButtons[location].isEnabled())
                {
                    setMove(mGame.HUMAN_PLAYER, location);

                    int winner = mGame.checkForWinner();

                    if (winner == 0)
                    {
                        mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_computer);
                        int move = mGame.getComputerMove();
                        setMove(mGame.ANDROID_PLAYER, move);
                        winner = mGame.checkForWinner();

                    }
                    if (winner == 0)
                            mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_human);
                    else if (winner == 1)
                    {
                        mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_tie);
                        mTieCounter++;
                        mTieCount.setText(Integer.toString(mTieCounter));
                        mGameOver = true;
                    }       
                    else if (winner ==2)
                    {
                        mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_human_wins);
                        mHumanCounter++;
                        mHumanCount.setText(Integer.toString(mHumanCounter));
                        mGameOver = true;
                    }
                    else if (winner ==3)
                    {
                        mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_android_wins);
                        mAndroidCounter++;
                        mAndroidCount.setText(Integer.toString(mAndroidCounter));
                        mGameOver = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void setMove(char player, int location)
    {
        mGame.setMove(player,location);
        mBoardButtons[location].setEnabled(false);
        mBoardButtons[location].setText(String.valueOf(player));
        if (player == mGame.HUMAN_PLAYER)
            mBoardButtons[location].setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        else
        {
            mBoardButtons[location].setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
    }



}
```

Its working here as i do not use appcompact 7 for my development, i used activity to extend your class and i have not use your menu.xml either , first delete that file and try building your code if that does not work use this file it is working fine my side with game restarting and application closing also. 
Thanks Use this and get back in case of any issue.
see its working here [image]

Comment: Thanks for the usefull command, I understand it and changed it. But when I try to run the .apk on my phone it closes the application directly, so there is still a error somewhere I guess.

Comment: from the log i can see the there is some mistake in casting the id to a view can you edit your question and post your layout xml.Since in log there is mentioned that you are casting textview to a button.

Comment: I added the whole layout xml, hope you can find something in it, its quite big

Comment: you are using eclipse right just place cursor under r.id.ten and r.id.eleven while pressing control button and see if it is taking you to right buttons then tell me.

Comment: so its just the problem of application installation just uninstall the application from your emulator or device then regenerate your apk file meaning just delete it from bin folder clean the project then gain try with fresh apk it should work. As you are saying there is only one resource pointed by id ten and id eleven and they are buttons.

Comment: I tried this now some times, keeps giving me the error

Comment: I could give the the whole code if you want, but maybe I should make a new post on this forum?

Comment: same log what is at your line location 46 in mainactivity.

Comment: new post will no need just edit the question and post you relevant code here

Comment: just give me image as before

Comment: okay im going to update my question now. are those classes enough: mainactivity.java activity_main.xml strings.xml?

Comment: Hey I tried to delete the appcompat, but I get the same error when I try to open the app on my phone. When I put the appcompat back in the code, it works

Comment: it is working now then good since its was simply library or eclipse code cleaning error.

Comment: You sure, because when I press the 2 buttons at the downside of the app, nothing is happening. While the left down button should start a new game, and the right left button should exit the app. Is it working at your side?

Comment: yup put some log in onclick and see your onclick is getting called or put toast to verify.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it so that `MainActivity` implements `View.OnClickListener`:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener { ...
```

Then your onClick method will be called when the button is clicked.

Comment: Thanks for the command, I think this was indeed the problem. But somehow my application fails to open